# Multiple monitor with Linux

Tags: arch-linux, desktop, desktop-environment, monitors, openbox

I' m installing Arch Linux with OpenBox, at the moment I've only downloaded OpenBox and tint2, but I have to install all the necessary. Before doing everything I'd like to know how to use my two monitor, showing two different desktops (desktop1 and desktop2) and if is there a way to keep on a monitor always the same desktop and instead having the possibility to have on the other monitor more than one desktop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used `arandr`, this utility allows to save a script configuring your two screens. (I know there is also the utility`xrandr` but I have not used it.)

I have added this script to my startup in fluxbox (I don't know where to put it for openbox) so each time a session is started, my two monitors get configured.

I don't understand what you mean with desktop 1 and 2... 
in my configuration one workspace is displayed over the two screens, giving twice space as usual for one workspace.

I have several workspaces, and if I switch between them, then I switch workspace for the two screens.